# Notation: why is it called inertia (inertial degree and inertia group)

Tags: terminology, algebraic-number-theory, math-history

A classmate recently asked me why the inertial degree and inertia group are named this way, and I realized I have no idea. Is there any historical reason for this naming convention? As far as I can see there is no connection to physics.

Comment: It's a very good question, I also wonder the same. The explanation that I thought of (but I have no idea whether it's right or not) is that for example inert primes are primes who "don't change their status" when you pass to a bigger number ring, in the sense that they remain prime (close an eye on the mathematical inaccuracy). This sounds analogous the use of the term inertia in physics for the resistance of an object to change its status.